# HTML CSS image not fit parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a website based on Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row padding_zero">
    <div class="col section px-0">
      <img class="img-trans padding_zero" src="./svg/clouds-00.svg" style="margin-top: -150px"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding_zero">
    <h1 class="pick_your_color animate">Choose Your Color</h1>
  </div>

.img-trans {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

And I have a problem that the image is always going out from the parent div, any idea what is the problem?

Comment: `margin-top: -150px`?

Comment: Is the image going out of the div when you resize the screen or when you load the page?

Comment: @WilliamG it always going out of div, but if I resize it even got more out of the div

Comment: I think adding `width: 100%` and `height:100%` to your `.img-trans` class will help. As was mentioned by @Pardip Lal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object-fit` to adjust the size of an element with a parent element.

1. fill: This is the default value that stretches the image according
   to the parent, regardless of the aspect ratio.
2. Contains: By considering the aspect ratio, it caches the image
   according to the parent.
3. cover: The image fills the height and width of your box, and once
   again maintains its aspect ratio but often crops the image.
4. none: The image is displayed regardless of the parent size.
5. scale-down: The image compares the difference between the two and is
   included to find the smallest size of the concrete object.

```css
.img-trans {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-trans {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Because your image size may be bigger than its parent size,
you must define the image's width and height.